# Migrate SQL Server database to SQL Azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

What's the best way to move a normal SQL server database to SQL Azure? Is it right that you can't restore from a backup file? The only way I've found so far is to script the database (and its data) and run those scripts on the SQL Azure database but this is slow when you have lots of data.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the SQL Azure Migration Wizard if running SQL 2008: http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/

For older versions the best thing I've seen is to either first upgrade to 2008 then port, or (unfortunately) to port the data using scripts as you've suggested. If you have to do so, might I suggest [SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com/) for generating your scripts?

Comment: I just migrated a simple database using the wizard and it worked first time with no hicups.

Comment: Have in mind that HierarchyId type fields have issues migrating. Even today (September 2012)

Answer (score 1):

1. Patch SQL Management Studio 2014 with the latest patches
2. Connect to your onsite sql server
3. Right click Database > Tasks > Deploy Database to Windows Azure SQL
4. DONE!

Thank you:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brunoterkaly/archive/2013/09/26/migrating-an-on-premises-sql-server-2012-database-to-windows-azure-sql-database.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use the SQL Azure Migration Wizard if running SQL 2008:

- http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/
- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/The-best-way-to-migrate-6c4a7326

Comment: A bit more detail would be nice. The link can go stale, and later visitors will like to know if it makes sense to so hunting.

Answer (score 0):

Be warned, backup your local copy before attempting SQLAzureMW.  If the BCP entries aren't just right, it will target your local DB instead of Azure.  Just recently had SQLAzureMW v3.3.9 successfully create tables on Azure, but (re)load the data (rows) in the source (local) DB.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

SqlServer DataBase > Task > ExportData > Source > Destination

All Done..

Comment: I tried this method and I ran into a lot of troubles because it doesn't take care of any FK constraint automatically, leaving you with a headache. 
Typically, you have table A with a column that is a FK on table B you're gonna have to export table B otherwise table A will fail (and the whole process will fail).

Answer (score 0):

Use Microsoft Data migration assistant tool which can be downloaded from here. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53595

First you have to install it. By using the Azure portal create new SQL database.Now you can deploy your local SQL database into Azure SQL database. If you have some warnings at the end of the migration process please ignore it.